# Windows Update KB4524147 Doesn't Work on Computers with 1903 Upgrade

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, sccm-2012

We have computers which were 1803 and have been upgraded to 1903 using SCCM to push out the upgrade using a service plan.

After this is deployed we are then deploying the update KB4524147 to the laptops using SCCM. The update will show as compliant in monitoring although it is not installed on the computer.

I then tried downloading the update manually from the online catalog online, but that didn't work either. The error message states that it is not applicable to the system. I tried different versions and am sure that I had the right one.

If I take a computer of the same make and model and install an image of 1903 (not an upgrade, but fresh install of Windows 10 1903) then I am able to download this very same update and install it.

It appears that the ones which were upgraded somehow are retaining information that makes it appear to be 1803 still to the update. Please can someone let me know where to start looking in order to troubleshoot this issue as I am stuck at this point?

Thanks.

Comment: Try installing the latest servicing stack upgrade from [ADV990001](https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-US/security-guidance/advisory/ADV990001) first.

Comment: Installing the servicing stack upgrade has not made any difference, it still doesn't recognize it as being for the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install the newest version of Windows 10, you are most likely at version 1903.30. You can not directly update to version 1903.388. I would try approving all the updates listed [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4498140) first.

Comment: If I run winver on a computer which is an upgrade to 1903 and one which is a fresh install of 1903 then the version shows the same. It shows as "10.0.18362 N/A Build 18362"

Comment: What does it say after 18362? should say 18362.xxx

Comment: It says 418 on both

Comment: Hi Joe, I went to the webpage you have linked in your post and started installing the updates in sequence. I can install KB4522355 successfully, but KB4517389, KB4524147 and KB4517211 give the not applicable message.

Comment: That's because KB4522355 supersedes all the other updates. With windows 10, each update in most cases includes all previous updates.  What you want to look at is the build number. In the case of KB4522355, the build number should be 18362.449. As long as the build number is the highest available, your machine is up to date.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks, that sort of makes sense, but the confusing thing is that the image was done before the October cumulative update was released, yet it shows the version as 18362.449 as soon as you log in fresh from it being applied to a computer.

Comment: The screen shot in the link shows what happens when I try the cumulative update on a computer which is at version 18362.418. https://ibb.co/m03Qwhj

Comment: Can someone advise on this please.

Comment: KB4524147 is not applicable to your system because you have KB4517389 installed. Once a newer update is installed on your machine, the older update longer applies because the new update supersedes the previous update.  This behavior is new to Windows 10 where previous versions required all the updates to be installed in most cases. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4517389

Comment: Thanks, we ran some tests on other computers and this seems to be the case.